# Как сделать систему завершения аукционов?

Tags: java, concurrency, playframework

Проблема:
Есть аукционы с определенным временем завершения. В это время нужно проставить им статус и перестать принимать ставки. Взять оплату с покупателя и т.д. Как сделать завершение торгов?
Мое решение: Сделать кэш вида Map<время окончания, акцион> и сделать задачу в отдельном потоке, которая будет брать значения по ключу из кэша и завершать ауцион.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            while(true) {
                doSomething
            }
        });
```

Я понимаю, что этот кусок будет увеличивать нагрузку на CPU. У кого-нибудь есть примеры более элегантного решения?

Comment: Может быть Quartz или TimerTask?

Comment: `В это время нужно проставить им статус` зачем просталять статус, если его можно вычислить? `getStatus(auction)=>if (auction.endTime < now) return closed else return active` ?

Comment: `перестать принимать ставки` ну добавьте проверку в свой API, что 1) список аукционов со ставками не долже содержать уже закрытые аукционы 2) при сохранении ставки проверяйте если аукцион уже закрытый - то ставка не принимается.

Comment: `Взять оплату с покупателя` тут уже нужен таймер. То есть что то, что будет триггерить вас каждые, например, 15 минут, и вы каждые 15 минут будете выбирать из БД аукционы, что были завершены, но ещё не обработаны, и обрабатывать их.

Comment: На счет статусов и проверки аукционов при ставке вы правы. Проблема в том, что оплату нужно брать сразу по завершении торгов. 15 минут могут быть неприемлемы.

Comment: узнайте, какое время будет приемлемо. Например, если 15 минут сократить до 1 минуты или 30 секунд. Если надо прямо секунда в секунду, то, конечно, просто триггером с интевалом тут не обойтись - придется каждый аукцион планировать отдельным таймером или искать готовые решения для такого, типа Quartz

Comment: А список аукционов у вас в каком виде, как часто они добавляются и может ли добавиться аукцион, который при этом будет завершаться раньше, чем уже имевшиеся до этого ? Потому как стандартное решение - получить список всех ожидаемых аукционов, отсортировать по времени завершения. Далее идем по этому массиву и пока текущее время меньше времени завершения закрываем, как только у очередного время больше текущего рассчитываем разницу во времени и усыпляем поток на это время. Но если вдруг могут появляться внеочредные придется будить поток при перестройке списка

Comment: Стартует система, в кэш добавляются все активные аукционы. Может добавиться аукцион, который завершится ранее, чем имеющиеся. Так же, если у аукциона осталось меньше 5 минут и прилетела ставка, то время догоняется до 5 минут и так пока ставок больше не будет. При добавлении аукциона, он добавляется в кэш.

Comment: ну если они у вас все в оперативке, то все примерно так как я сказал, только продумать как усыпить поток так, что бы он спал заданное время и при этом его можно было разбудить из другого потока (того, что новый аукцион добавляет, в случае если время завершения нового аукциона меньше времени самого первого в очереди, отсортированной по времени). А если у аукциона время увеличилось, ничего страшного, в очереди двигаете его на свое место и все. поток закрытия проснется, увидит что нечего закрывать и заснет до следующего в верху списка

Answer (score 0):

Итак. Что я сделал. При старте нового аукциона, я стартую новую джобу с триггером, который выставлен на время окончания аукциона. Джоба берет все активные аукционы за время триггера и начинает их обрабатывать по очереди. В это же время, производя списания денег со счета победителя. При старте системы так же берутся все активные аукционы и на них заводятся джобы. Всё сделано с помощью Quartz.